# Foundation 6 dropdown menu, can't click on submenus on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Hello fellow developers.. I have a problem with the foundation dropdown menu, and after quite a while of tackling the problem I search for your help, foundation gurus.

I am using foundation 6.2.4-full. I've created a dropdown menu but I noticed an issue, the problem lies when using the menu with mobile devices (try on iphone 4). It's submenu items aren't clickable. For example, click on the Map option, and then try to click on Pokemons sub-option. The code is embedded below. 
I can't find the problem, I am quite new to foundation, perhaps I'm missing an important option?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="device-width=width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation/foundation.min.css">
    <script src="/js/jquery_2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/foundation/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
</script>
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="/">Map</a>
            <ul class="menu submenu vertical nested" data-submenu>
                <li><a href="">Pokemons</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Poke Gyms</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Poke Stops</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">news</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a>Guides</a>
            <ul class="menu submenu vertical nested" data-submenu>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Game guides</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Site guides</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyone? Maybe an advice or something, maybe use a third party plugin if the menu is bugged?

Comment: Your load order is wrong, load the jquery and javascripts in the footer of your doc, then fire off foundation there, not in the head of your document - your snippet is throwing a jQuery error: "     Guides
        Game guides
        Site guides

{
  "message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 22,
  "colno": 5
}"

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that the order is wrong. It generates an error here just because it can't find the files, I was showing my layout for others to understand what versions and files I use

Comment: It helps to have the code be as correct as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, give it a go on mobile, I think Foundation will detect mobile and turn the hover into a click, all events are in their documentation here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html.

Here's my example that works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="device-width=width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="/">Map</a>
            <ul class="menu submenu vertical nested" data-submenu>
                <li><a href="">Pokemons</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Poke Gyms</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Poke Stops</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">news</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a>Guides</a>
            <ul class="menu submenu vertical nested" data-submenu>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Game guides</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Site guides</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And to change the behaviour to click on mobile, follow the instructions here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html#advanced-layout, use the "Responsive Toggler plugin".

Comment: I've already found another solution. Using a 3-rd party library at the moment that suits my needs. But thank you for your reply, I'll check the code and write back.

Comment: Cool what did you go with?

Comment: Hey Nathaniel, sorry for the long absence.. I have checked your code, but it gives me the same as my code, you literally can't click on the sub-menu that's popping up. I don't know what the problem is and I don't want to fiddle with it at the moment.
I just wanted to say that I'm using "SmartMenus jQuery Plugin" from http://www.smartmenus.org/ and it works for me at the moment. Hopefully I'll understand what was wrong with the foundation menu in the future, or maybe they correct their bugs.. Thank you for your attention to my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Did you do the fixes I suggested? Might just be a jQuery/javascript conflict rather than a code bug in Foundation. Anyway, thanks for the reply and I'm glad you're moving forward.

Comment: I've literary inserted your code into my project, and since your code doesn't use my project files, it should have worked.. But it doesn't work correctly for some reason. I could even show you a video.. But at the moment it's not worth the hassle since I have resolved my problem already. Thanks again.